# How to get shared likes on the main page posts itself?

Tags: facebook, facebook-pages, facebook-groups

I am having about 70-80% likes on my shared posts but they don't have effect on my main page.
I usually share my page on groups and share with friends and whenever I get likes on the shared posts there is no effect on the main post in my Page.
Is there any way so that likes on my shared post to my main post on a Facebook page ?

Comment: Are you sharing your own page post from your page or other pages' posts?

Comment: [This question helped me](https://www.facebook.com/help/community/question/?id=1126387734087896)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no way to do so. When you share a post from any account, or into any group, it is considered as a new post. So all the Likes, Comments are associated only to the shared posts. You cannot get it on main Page posts.